# Problema caracteres especiales excel - html

Tags: php, excel

Buenos días.
Estoy pasando el contenido de un excel a una tabla, al mostrarme los datos de tabla los caracteres especiales me aparecen con un �.
El excel esta en formato xls.
Código PHP

```
    require_once ("Excel/reader.php");  
    $datos = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();  

    $datos->read($_POST['archivo']); 
    $celdas = $datos->sheets[0]['cells']; 

    $i = 1;  
    echo "<table width='300' align='center' border=1>";
    while($celdas[$i][1]!='') 
    {  
        echo "<tr><td width='150' align='center'>".$celdas[$i][1]."</td>
        <td width='150' align='center'>".$celdas[$i][2]."</td>
        <td width='150' align='center'>".$celdas[$i][3]."</td>
        <td width='150' align='center'>".$celdas[$i][4]."</td>
        <td width='150' align='center'>".$celdas[$i][5]."</td>
        <td width='150' align='center'>".$celdas[$i][6]."</td>
        <td width='150' align='center'>".$celdas[$i][7]."</td>
        <td width='150' align='center'>".$celdas[$i][8]."</td></tr> ";
        $i++;  
    }  
    echo "</table>";
```

En las cabeceras he usado   `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>`. Tambien he usado la función `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");`

Comment: ¿Muestras el contenido dónde, en un HTML? ¿Puedes verificar en el **código fuente** que efectivamente las cabeceras están establecidas a utf-8? ¿Usas alguna librería?

Comment: @A.Cedano si en un HTML y las cabeceras estan establecidad a utf-8. Uso la libreria PHPExcelReader

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/79588/65

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por niveles:

1. **El documento.** Asegúrate que efectivamente la codificación del HTML es `UTF-8`. Para ello revisa el código fuente del HTML donde estás queriendo presentar los datos. Lo podrás hacer activando las opciones de desarrollo del navegador y yendo al menú `Desarrollo / Ver código fuente` o algo parecido. Debes revisar el atributo `meta` del HTML y verificar que no está repetido más abajo, suele suceder a veces que por error hay varios meta de codificación, primando en ese caso el último.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Si eso está bien. Pasamos a un segundo nivel de revisión: **el manejo de los datos**. La codificación por defecto de la librería PHPExcelReader  es `UTF-8`. No obstante, [hay reportes de problemas con respecto a la codificación en su página de Github](https://github.com/jasonrogena/php-excel-reader/issues/8). Por ejemplo:

> In version 2.11, the line 771 decides whether or not a string is
> ascii
> encoded or not. As it seems this is not working reliably, for only UTF16LE
> strings are "decoded" to the requested defaultEncoding.
>
> ```
> My workaround/hack for now is to replace line 771 with this:
>
> $retstr = ($asciiEncoding) ? iconv('cp1250', $this->_defaultEncoding,
> $retstr) : $this->_encodeUTF16($retstr);
>
> I'm not fully convinced using an hardcoded encoding of cp1250 is a good
> idea but it seems to work in my testcase.
> ```

Lo que dice es que para resolverlo ha cambiado la línea 771 por esto:

```
$retstr = ($asciiEncoding) ? iconv('cp1250', $this->_defaultEncoding,
$retstr) : $this->_encodeUTF16($retstr);
```

**Nota:** Ese reporte es del año 2015 y corresponde a la versión 2.11 de la librería. No sé si sea la versión que estás usando.

En Stackoverflow en inglés hay varias respuestas **con esos cambios de valores en líneas** pero varían según la versión de la librería como es normal. Sea como sea, eso de estar modificando uno mismo los archivos de una librería no es la solución deseable ni es solución definitiva. Son errores que deberían ser corregidos en nuevas versiones de la librería por sus creadores.

4. **Verificar la codificación de los datos que generan el archivo Excel**. De acuerdo a lo comentado los datos se pueden estar generando con otra codificación. Suele ocurrir por ejemplo en archivos Excel generados en Mac OSx. En ese caso una posible solución sería generarlo en Google Sheets o en Excel Windows.
5. **Cambiar de librería**. Si la codificación está bien establecida en todas partes y sigue dando problema, es posible que [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) sea una mejor opción.

---

### POSTDATA

Esta respuesta es antigua y basada en `PHPExcel`. Quienes la lean deben saber que esta librería ya no es mantenida y que la librería que se recomienda actualmente es [`PhpSpreadsheet`](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet). No obstante, el problema tratado aquí: **la codificación**, puede presentarse independietemente de la librería que estemos usando.

Comment: Me he dado cuenta que el problema es el archivo excel, porque he lo he guardado en csv separado por comas y lo he leido en php y pasa lo mismo, he abierto el csv en sublime y no tenia el utf-8 al ponerselo todos los carcteres especiales se sustituian por una ?, la solucion seria en la cofiguracion del excel cambiar la codificación, pero estoy en mac y los menus no son iguales y estoy buscando por todos los lados pero no encuentro la opcion que me permita cambiarla.

Comment: @BorjaCalvo Yo he tenido problemas de encodaje con CSV creados desde documentos Excel en Mac. Para evitar eso lo que he hecho ha sido pasarlos a una **[Google Sheet](https://www.google.es/intl/es/sheets/about/)** y generar desde allí el CSV, cuando lo hago así no tengo ningún problema. Aún probando con los _formatos especiales_ que aparecen abajo, cuando se trata de exportar a CSV, no me ha funcionado bien.

Comment: Si con Google Sheet el csv funciona perfectamente. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Habría que dar por resuelta esta pregunta o bien eliminarla. Me alegro de que haya funcionado.

Comment: No se exactamente como se le da como resulta

Comment: @BorjaCalvo Activando la flecha de cotejo, a la izquierda de la respuesta que indica la resolución del problema.

Answer (score 0):

El problema puede surgir porque estás definiendo el formato de salida, pero no el de lectura.
Mira a ver si esto te sirve:

```
$data->setOutputEncoding('UTF-8'); 
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($_POST['archivo'],true,"UTF-8");
```

Puedes probar con UTF-16 si sigue fallando.

Comment: Sigue fallando. Puede ser algun problema del excel ?