# Cómo hacer que Excel abra correctamente un archivo CSV con diacríticos al hacer doble clic en el mismo

Tags: javascript, excel, csv

El usuario cuenta con Excel como aplicación predeterminada para abrir archivos CSV y desea que luego de descargar un archivo CSV de mi aplicación al hacer doble clic en este y ser abierto en Excel, los diacríticos se vean correctamente.

Los datos son

```
País    Estado      Ciudad
México  Nuevo León  Monterrey
México  Tamaulipas  Güémez
```

pero se ven de la siguiente forma

```
Estado  Ciudad  
MÃ©xico Nuevo LeÃ³n Monterrey
MÃ©xico Tamaulipas  GÃ¼Ã©mez
```

Adapté el código de [Use JavaScript to Export Your Data as CSV](https://halistechnology.com/2015/05/28/use-javascript-to-export-your-data-as-csv/) para poder explicar la situación de forma general con un ejemplo completo mínimo y verificable.

- Se tiene datos en una matriz de objetos que incluyen diacríticos
- Se genera un enlace para descargar los datos como archivos CSV.

```js
var datos = [
  {
    País: "México",
    Estado: "Nuevo León",
    Ciudad: "Monterrey"
  },
  {
    País: "México",
    Estado: "Tamaulipas",
    Ciudad: "Güémez"
  }
];

function convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV(args) {
  var result, ctr, keys, columnDelimiter, lineDelimiter, data;

  data = args.data || null;
  if (data == null || !data.length) {
    return null;
  }

  columnDelimiter = args.columnDelimiter || ',';
  lineDelimiter = args.lineDelimiter || '\n';

  keys = Object.keys(data[0]);

  result = '';
  result += keys.join(columnDelimiter);
  result += lineDelimiter;

  data.forEach(function(item) {
    ctr = 0;
    keys.forEach(function(key) {
      if (ctr > 0) result += columnDelimiter;

      result += item[key];
      ctr++;
    });
    result += lineDelimiter;
  });

  return result;
}

function downloadCSV(args) {
  var data, filename, link;

  var csv = convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV({
    data: datos
  });
  if (csv == null) return;

  filename = args.filename || 'export.csv';

  if (!csv.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
    csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8' + csv;
  }
  data = encodeURI(csv);

  link = document.createElement('a');
  link.setAttribute('href', data);
  link.setAttribute('download', filename);
  link.click();
}
```

```html
<a href='#' onclick='downloadCSV({ filename: "ciudades-con-diacríticos.csv" });'>Descargar CSV</a>
```

Sobre lo que he intentado para solucionarlo encontré que agregar el caracter BOM genera una excepción ya que utf-8 es de caracter simple y no funciona en Mac, y también intenté reemplazando `utf-8` por `utf-8-sig` y agregué los octetos 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF pero no me funcionarion.

**Pregunta en inglés relacionada**

[Microsoft Excel mangles Diacritics in .csv files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/155097/1595451)

Answer (score 8):

> He probado con Windows 10 64bits con Excel 2016 y funciona. Si pruebas con otro SO y/o versión de Excel por favor deja un comentario con los datos.

La solución es usar utf-16 en lugar de utf-8 y agregar el caracter de marca de orden de bytes (BOM por sus siglas en inglés)  `\uFEFF`.

El código de la pregunta quedaría de la siguiente forma

```js
var datos = [
  {
    País: "México",
    Estado: "Nuevo León",
    Ciudad: "Monterrey"
  },
  {
    País: "México",
    Estado: "Tamaulipas",
    Ciudad: "Güémez"
  }
];

function convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV(args) {
  var result, ctr, keys, columnDelimiter, lineDelimiter, data;

  data = args.data || null;
  if (data == null || !data.length) {
    return null;
  }

  columnDelimiter = args.columnDelimiter || ',';
  lineDelimiter = args.lineDelimiter || '\n';

  keys = Object.keys(data[0]);

  result = '';
  result += keys.join(columnDelimiter);
  result += lineDelimiter;

  data.forEach(function(item) {
    ctr = 0;
    keys.forEach(function(key) {
      if (ctr > 0) result += columnDelimiter;

      result += item[key];
      ctr++;
    });
    result += lineDelimiter;
  });

  return result;
}

function downloadCSV(args) {
  var data, filename, link;

  var csv = convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV({
    data: datos
  });
  if (csv == null) return;

  filename = args.filename || 'export.csv';

  if (!csv.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
    csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-16,\uFEFF' + csv;
  }
  data = encodeURI(csv);

  link = document.createElement('a');
  link.setAttribute('href', data);
  link.setAttribute('download', filename);
  link.click();
}
```

```html
<a href='#' onclick='downloadCSV({ filename: "ciudades-con-diacríticos.csv" });'>Descargar CSV</a>
```

Comment: he probado con Office 2007, Office 2010, y el 2013 y todo perfecto.

Answer (score 3):

Otra solución es agregar el `%EF%BB%BF` ([utf-8 BOM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_de_orden_de_bytes#Representaciones_de_las_marcas_de_orden_de_bytes_para_cada_codificaci.C3.B3n)) al principio del texto CSV

```js
var datos = [
  {
    País: "México",
    Estado: "Nuevo León",
    Ciudad: "Monterrey"
  },
  {
    País: "México",
    Estado: "Tamaulipas",
    Ciudad: "Güémez"
  }
];

function convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV(args) {
  var result, ctr, keys, columnDelimiter, lineDelimiter, data;

  data = args.data || null;
  if (data == null || !data.length) {
    return null;
  }

  columnDelimiter = args.columnDelimiter || ',';
  lineDelimiter = args.lineDelimiter || '\n';

  keys = Object.keys(data[0]);

  result = '';
  result += keys.join(columnDelimiter);
  result += lineDelimiter;

  data.forEach(function(item) {
    ctr = 0;
    keys.forEach(function(key) {
      if (ctr > 0) result += columnDelimiter;

      result += item[key];
      ctr++;
    });
    result += lineDelimiter;
  });

  return result;
}

function downloadCSV(args) {
  var data, filename, link;

  var csv = convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV({
    data: datos
  });
  if (csv == null) return;

  filename = args.filename || 'export.csv';

  data = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF' + encodeURI(csv);

  link = document.createElement('a');
  link.setAttribute('href', data);
  link.setAttribute('download', filename);
  link.click();
}
```

```html
<a href='#' onclick='downloadCSV({ filename: "ciudades-con-diacríticos.csv" });'>Descargar CSV</a>
```

Comment: @Rubén, leyendo la respuesta en `SOen` a la que haces referencia, ahi mismo dice lo que comentas (no hay referencia a nada) solo que supuestamente en `Excel 2003 y versiones anteriores` y que en `Excel 2007 y posteriores` ya no da error. La verdad que desde el 2008 al 2017 es muy posible que hayan lanzado alguna actualización para solucionar esto.

Comment: Bueno, pues en la pregunta, de forma muy escueta sintetizo los comentarios en la pregunta referida. En cualquier caso, en Windows 10 64bits con Excel 2016 me funciona bien tu código. ¿Me podrías decir con cuál SO y Excel has probado?

Comment: @Rubén, Tengo exactamente los mismos, Windows 10 64bits y Excel 2016

Comment: @Rubén, lo acabo de probar en [`macOS Sierra (v10.12.3) y TextEdit`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mjho4.png) y también funciona

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60927/discussion-between-ruben-and-marcos-gallardo).

Answer (score 0):

Saludos, las soluciones que plantean mas arriba resuelven el inconveniente, pero no lo solucionan, aqui el problema es in problema de fondo, intervienen varios factores, dentro de los que destaca el Sistema operativo (cada uno esta configurado diferente)

Mi recomendacion es que no exportes a CVS, sino directamente a excel, con esto, almenos no tendras problemas con los caracteres,

De igual forma no te recomiendo que uses javascript para esta labor, major genera el reporte en el servidor y exportalo al cliente

Comment: El problema no tiene que ver con el sistema operativo sino con Excel y podría decirse que las versiones antiguas tenían dos problemas, la codificación predeterminada y una excepción que ocurría en archivos utf-8 con BOM. Cada formato tiene sus ventajas y desventajas, la pregunta no trata sobre ello. En cuando a la recomendación con JavaScript falta que digas el motivo por el que no lo recomiendas. De todas formas, gracias por responder.

Answer (score 0):

¿Y si a tu HTML le agregas el meta:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

?

También, especifícale al servidor web que la codificación de lo que "sirve" es UTF-8. Dependiendo del servidor que uses, esto cambiará. En apache tienes que agregar al httpd.conf (o equivalente) lo siguiente:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Comment: Lo de la etiqueta meta no tiene ningún efecto en el caso de servir un csv

Answer (score 0):

Debes añadir la UTF-8 BOM al comienzo, algo como:

```
var contenidocsv = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF";
```

Se probó en excel 2013 y funcionó.

Comment: Es prácticamente lo mismo que se recomienda en la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/80811/65) de Marcos Gallardo, sólo que sin un ejemplo completo, con la salvedad que se hace mención de la versión de Excel en la que se probó.

Answer (score 0):

Te estás complicando la vida intentando reinventar la rueda. Excel tiene opciones para importar un CSV con cualquier codificación de caracteres.

1. Datos > Obtener Datos desde el texto/CSV

   > [image: Datos > Obtener datos]
2. Seleccionar el archivo
3. Seleccionar codificación y Delimitador

   > [image: Opciones de importación]
4. Click en el botón `Cargar` y **listo**!

---

Si se ve mal, estás usando la codificación incorrecta, probá con otra. Las más comunes son:

- 65001: Unicode (UTF-8)
- 1252: Europeo occidental (Windows)