# Problema al cargar csv a Phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, csv

Desde un archivo en excel genero un archivo csv el cual quiero importar a PhpMyAdmin usando la opción Importar del PhpMyAdmin.
Pero el primer campo, que es la primary key, solo reconoce los 3 ultimos caracteres.

```
INSERT INTO `tabla` VALUES ('214', '90', '2', '1', '201802', '2018-01-11'...)
```

El registro original es este:

```
21214   90  2   1   20182   2018-01-11
```

Y el primer campo es int(10) unsigned.
Al generar el csv, lo abro con Bloc de Notas y lo grabo con codificación UTF-8.
Cuando trabajaba con office 2010 no tenia problema, ahora utilizo office 2016 y tengo este problema.

Comment: Pero... ¿cómo generaste ese `INSERT INTO...`? ¿Tu PK tiene el tamaño suficiente para registrar un valor como `21214`? ¿No lo estará truncando por problemas de tamaño de la Primary Key?

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la pregunta. El campo es int(10). Y el excel que estoy generando tiene dos registros (es una prueba)

Comment: Si tienes una cuenta de Google sugeriría que intentes generar el CSV con Google Sheets, ya que dices que en versiones anteriores de Windows no tenías problemas.

Comment: La información original se genera en excel, lo que hice fue abrir ese excel con la hoja de cálculo de Google Docs y generé el CSV desde allí, cargó bien. Y ahora cómo cierro la pregunta?

Comment: La puedes eliminar, o si quieres podría proporcionar una respuesta. Es un problema frecuente y no es la primera vez que indico esta solución, que ha funcionado. Revisaré si alguno de los usuarios decidió guardar la pregunta. Quizá deba existir una como punto de referencia. Ahora reviso y te digo.

Comment: El tema fue tratando en comentarios, en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/79439/29967). En el pasado yo tuve problemas con la codificación, subiendo archivos CSV de una hoja Excel a MySQL y mi solución fue pasar la hoja Google Sheets, exportar de allí y subir los datos. Cuando empecé a hacerlo así, no tuve ningún tipo de problema.